# Prevent Prettier from Auto-Wrapping Inner Element Tags in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, web, prettier

I prefer the following code formatting style in VSCode:

```
<ul class="html-formatting">
    <li>This is a <b>bold</b> paragraph.</li>
</ul>
```

However, Prettier automatically formats it like this:

```
<ul class="html-formatting">
    <li>
        this is a
        <b>bold</b>
        paragraph
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I configure Prettier to avoid wrapping the content inside element tags? I want to maintain the original structure without the auto-wrapping inside the `<li>` tag.

Comment: might want to read https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity. I'll bet this question is a duplicate but am too lazy right now to find the dup target.

Comment: I already tried all of those, but unfortunately still not achieve my preference

Comment: then you should have stated so in your question post. please edit your question post to say that you already tried that.